# How would one go about proving humans have really been to outer space?

Tags: astronauts, nasa, atmosphere, cost, travel

**Background**: I am 40 years old, and in my entire life the only face to face eyewitness event that I can remember where humans actually observed an attempt to fly into outer space, the craft exploded and showered its fiery remains - including 5 dead astronauts - down over the Earth as soon as it reached the atmosphere. I have seen no other real eyewitness evidence.

As an Australian, I also live really far away from any launch or landing sites, with all of them too far to be directly observable even through a powerful telescope. I have never witnessed any space exploration endeavors in person and all I have available to me is accounts by other people that I have never met in real life and videos on the Internet or recordings and interviews on the television or radio stations.

**Question**: How could I go about finding proof of mankind ever reaching outer space first hand, with astronauts doing moonwalks, spacewalks, whatnot when all of it seems unreal, happening somewhere else and never directly touching the grounds of my own country, which happens to be a whole continent of the planet Earth that I live on, while only having indirect and anecdotal evidence of it? I would take a word from any of you that have been a direct eyewitness to human space exploration, but preferably ask of you for any idea how I could prove that by holding something in my own hands that could only exist if that was true, or by doing my own direct observations, be an eyewitness myself and have proof beyond reasonable doubt?

**Is there any direct evidence of human space exploration that nobody on our planet could dismiss as circumstantial?**

Comment: In view of the responses by @ekerner , it's become clear that this is not so much about the space program, but about believing in anything for which one doesn't have first-hand evidence. I.e. this is a philosophical question and belongs more in [philosophy.stackexchange.com](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) than here.

Comment: The topic began when my children asked me what I know about men traveling in space. And now I am trying to learn how I will teach my children - and myself - where we are at with space travel, without embellishment or exaggeration.
When your young children look up at the stars with wonder and, while trying to fathom what seems like the impossible an unbelievable, ask you how the heck man could possible travel in space, you will see clearly that the philosophical side of the discussion goes hand in hand with the question.

Comment: In fact, the philosophy of science begins to pose epistemology questions from the very beginnings of physics, e.g. electricity and atomic theory. Have you ever seen "face to face" electrons crowded on the surface of a charged conductor? Atoms?.. Heck, having that level of skepticism one should have troubles accepting even the fact that the Earth is round.

Comment: I have been electrocuted. I am an electronics technician - among other hats - and I have worked much with electricity. Iv witnessed the way it behaves, and coerced it. As for atoms on a charged conductor, I have not seen that, and so being of sound mind I cannot say for sure if that is true. Even as a qualified and practiced electronics technician I cannot state that I know how electricity works at the molecular level, can anyone - other than theorists and other such dreamers kidding themselves?

Comment: Do you have $50,000,000 lying around? Because you can buy a ticket and GO to space yourself if you want. The Russians will be happy to let you tag along if you pay for the rocket!!

Comment: @corsiKa actually, the price tag may be up to *two orders of magnitude less* in the nearest future (several years). I can't quote exactly, but certain civil aerospace companies offer civilian suborbital flights for $200-250 thousand. That's *just* a quarter of one million dollars.

Comment: Wow this is awesome and real evidence. If anyone who has paid the fees and been to space would like to add comment that would be straight from the horses mouth, so to speak. Where would we find one of the buyers and invite them to share their experience?

Comment: It's funny, I actually still believe more that we've been to space than that North Dakota exists. I've met an astronaut, I've never met a single soul from North Dakota.

Comment: Actually, @ekerner, Prospero was launched from Woomera on Black Arrow (admittedly before you were born) and is still in orbit today.

Comment: God, this is controversial

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch ikr, and the most disturbing thing to me is the vote-down on the question, basically saying "Uhm, don't ask this question" lol :D

Answer (score 21):

Yes, humans **definitely** have been to outer space.

The easiest proof I can think of immediately is [this video](https://youtu.be/o8TssbmY-GM?t=1m22s) of commander [Chris Hadfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Hadfield) demonstrating wringing of a wet towel on the [ISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station).

Or [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uk9ptueTDwY) — it contains more than 200 seconds long uncut shot of a̶b̶s̶e̶n̶t̶ *micro*-gravity. It also shows vast interiors of the ISS, which are technically challenging to simulate in a "vomit comet", due to theirs volume and structure.

---

**Update:** [it isn't impossible](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/666) to *see astronauts spacewalking near the ISS* from the ground, given enough time, skill, and equipment. It has been done before.

However, you can still claim that the photographs could've been edited and/or made up. In this case, you'll have to repeat the observations yourself.

---

**Update2:** I can even add the following praise of modern communication technology (and publicity of the space program). **[You can talk live](http://www.nasa.gov/connect/hangout.html)** with astronauts inhabiting the ISS! With enough perseverance, you can even ask them to provide whatever proofs you'd find satisfactory. Just have enough patience and don't forget to take your son to the chat.

Comment: The low orbit of ISS is very close to Earth, Pluto is very far away in the outer solar system. But space with a lot of galaxies is huge. The Voyager probes are leaving our solar system, but nothing man made has ever left our own galaxy the milky way. Outer space may be far galaxies, but not our own solar system. Humans have been on the Moon very close to Earth.

Answer (score 18):

The problem here is that your standard of proof is ridiculous. By the same token, you'd have to doubt the existence of Moscow because you've never met anyone from that city.

> the only face to face eyewitness event that I can remember where humans actually observed an attempt to fly into outer space...

Then your memory must not be very good. There have been hundreds of manned launches that have been witnessed by [millions of people](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=shuttle%20launch%20crowd). The Apollo and early Shuttle launches had massive audiences that were able to see the spacecraft launch, and reach an altitude of dozens of km in a few minutes. For launches to higher inclinations, the Shuttle was visible [all the way up the US East Coast](http://www.nytimes.com/library/national/science/120198sci-shuttle.html).

These days, a few thousand dollars will buy you a VIP visit to Baikonur where you can [witness a launch yourself](http://rusadventures.com/tour1.shtml).

What you're saying basically is "I'd rather believe all of the millions of photos and thousands of hours of video are hoaxes and that millions of people are involved in a vast conspiracy to lie about every manned space program."

Back in the days of the Space Race, the US and USSR would not have hesitated to expose any attempt by the other to lie about sending men to space.

Comment: To doubt - or at least not vest full belief in - the existence of Moscow without first hand evidence would be considered by psychiatrists to be completely sane. To believe that Jesus killed a tree with a word 2000 years ago with no proof is considered by psychiatrists to be insane. The fact is that its very easy to lie and people do lie. For example: There is a planet named trinifalse in the ultifar quadrant, and if you dont believe that planet trinifalse exists then it must, because I am from there ;)

Comment: However I do find very useful your reference to the launches with audiences of people. That is undeniable. If an audience of people testify that they saw me come from trinifalse, then I likely come from trinifalse.

Comment: Sure, people lie. But to lie successfully for decades is very difficult. Eventually the liar will slip up. The chances of this increase with the number of people involved in the lie, and the number of people involved in the space program are huge.  Consider some of the most successful black programs in history: Bletchley Park, the SR-71. Their secrecy depended on several thousand people, not millions, and yet their secrecy was broken in less than 20 years.  Are you familiar with Occam's razor? We have piles of evidence of the space program being real and none of it being a lie.

Comment: @ekerner, *"...and lets just simply answer the question."* — Which parts of [my answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/how-would-one-go-about-proving-humans-have-really-been-to-outer-space/2434#2434) do not cover your question completely?

Comment: @ulidtko, your answer is great - the non philosophical parts - and does give light to my question.
Your references to the launches with audiences of people are exactly what I was looking for - as I already suggested.
If youre wanting the green tick then you may get it, but you cannot be the only person in this entire site that has some evidence that answers my question and so before jumping for joy I wanted to see what others may have to add.
We Trinifalsians are a patient people ;)

Comment: @ekerner you may need to understand that people on this site get so very little inspiration to answer your question. Likewise, the question score reflects the level of gratitude and trust which the [space exploration] community attains for someone claiming himself to have extraterrestrial origins. You may get warmer response on the sceptics SE site or maybe philosophy's one.

Comment: @ulidtko I dunno, this Q has received 10,000 views and earned me a famous question badge. Looks like Im not the only person pondering over it.And of the 10,000 views only 2 down atm. Makes it apparent who is the minority on this topic.

Comment: Hi again @ekerner! I'm not convinced that each one of those visits indicates direct interest to what your question inquires. Similarly to the Streisand effect, I speculate, people might just be curious about the strangely weird character who've asked such a question. Or, some might wonder what the community reaction to that was. Don't forget the network effects, where texts are being sent saying roughly "LOL look at this guy <link>". Anyhow, this [*ad populum*](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/) argument you make looks invalid to me; and I don't quite get what you're trying to prove.

Comment: Hi @ulidtko well to be honest you nailed it with 'invalid', and so at the risk of ruining a great thread imho, Im just having fun. You guys answered my question ages ago. As a trinifalsian (thanks Russell) I tend to dumbly stumble into interesting situations. And the interesting thing about this one is the old classic 'thou doest protest too much'. Feels like I tripped on faith, landed on belief, and was helped up with hope rather than knowledge, so its just a matter of time before Im back here looking for something more than hope to help me stand on the matter. But thats life on trinifalse :)

Comment: @ekerner well, welcome to the internet then. I assure you will discover *tons* of ways to have fun around here. That is to say, unless they ruin the internet completely, censor & dmca it to dust — the process of which is already commencing...

Comment: @ulidtko :) Fortunately for me as a coder: All of the limitations Iv seen so far enforced on the web are at the client (user agent eg browser) level, so anyone who can use curl or sockets can usually go beneath said layers. The tier 1 changes have mostly been related to monitoring what we are all doing tho, and gives them the data required to additionally restrict said. I dread to think what might happening if they start applying restrictions at the tier 1 level. I presume they have or will tho.

Comment: ... All such monitoring is of course only available to the mgrs of tier 1 (US gov and military), however most countries are putting in country level proxies so they too can enjoy capturing what we do. In AU its called the National Broadband Network (NBN) and sold to the unknowing as a great internet service. Unfortunately it doesnt even provide that :) I mean if theyre gonna sell us something on a lie they could at least make the lie believable.

Comment: @ekerner you've seen... not enough, to put it mildly. Try your curl on chinese or russian internet (sic). There used to be just one internet; now we have to country-qualify huge chunks of it — because no, hell no their censorship is client-based. Far from it.

Comment: The US and USSR exposing each other would be the definitive proof, unless you don't believe that Moscow doesn't exist.

Answer (score 13):

When the amount of evidence, circumstantial or direct, for a given proposition vastly outweighs evidence against that proposition, most reasonable people are willing to accept the proposition as true. This does occasionally lead to having to change your mind about a proposition when new evidence comes along; this is how the scientific method works.

In the specific case of space travel, consider this: [Germany launched some big rockets during WWII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-2_rocket), and some big rockets landed in England, and we have good circumstantial evidence that those were the same rockets, and some back-of-the-envelope calculations regarding energy from chemical reactions, volume of fuel, mass of rocket, models of aerodynamic drag, etc. all agree that, yes, a rocket using *that* design and *that* fuel can go *that* far.

After WWII, other countries (like the USA and USSR) then built bigger and better rockets, that could go further, and all of those seemed to perform more or less according to our models as well, and we improved our models to better align with our observations.

Eventually the USSR built [Vostok 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostok_1): a pod big enough to hold Yuri Gagarin, on top of a rocket big enough to, according to our calculations, throw that pod high enough that the atmosphere is thin enough that we call it "outer space". Lots of people saw the rocket take off, and later, far away, a pod fell out of the sky and [Yuri Gagarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Gagarin) landed, nearby, by parachute. One interesting thing here is that the USSR lied about that at the time and said he landed with the pod, so already this story is kind of fishy and you wouldn't be completely crazy to have doubts about this.

But since then, there have been [over 300 crewed spaceflights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_spaceflights), on rockets that we know quite a bit about, that clearly have taken off at point A and had parts reappear later at point B, with photographs and video of people getting into them at one end, photos and video of the beginning of the flight, and photos and video of very similar-looking people getting out of them at the other end, across more than half a century. [More than 550 individuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_astronauts_by_first_flight) have claimed to have flown in space; as far as I know, none have ever recanted the claim and said "it was a hoax"—and I'd ignore one or two voices out of 550 who claimed hoax anyway, given the evidence in favor.

That's a *lot* of circumstantial evidence.

At this point, even the most skeptical humans generally believe that the burden of proof is on those who doubt that human spaceflight happened. It seems, at this point, vastly easier to actually put people into space than to orchestrate a conspiracy of this scale.

If you want me to doubt the fact of crewed spaceflight, you have to explain to me where those rockets went, where the crew boarding them went, who the people were who exited similar-looking capsules hundreds and thousands of miles away, and most importantly, why we'd bother with such a scheme.

Most of this applies to anyone doubting the moon landings, as well. The ratio of evidence may be slightly less extreme, but there's still [a wealth of evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-party_evidence_for_Apollo_Moon_landings) in favor of them. A Saturn V rocket produces about 18km/s of delta-V; where was it going if not to the moon?

Comment: Thank you Russell. Very nice paper in many ways.
It seems you have primarily addressed your distaste for my lack of knowledge and evidence on the topic, rather than the actual question.
However in doing so you have almost answered the question...
Your comment "with photographs and live video" references the answer, and if you could provide said "photographs and live video", or at least sources and citations, then you will have the question answered.
Now I wish to try offer you some peace: Would I be correct as a software developer to be upset if you don't trust computers?
Thx, Eugene.

Comment: I'm a software developer and I have no idea what you mean by "trust computers"; I trust computers like I trust dynamite, chainsaws, and tigers.

It's not my job to provide you with the evidence you want, but if I felt like it was I'd start poking around in NASA's public historical web site. I'm quite certain they have plenty of evidence that isn't digitized and readily available, in addition.  http://www.nasa.gov/missions/past/index.html#.U2XgjF7BV74

Comment: Well you have a sense of humor. I trust computers as much as I trust programmers. Nice link! Thx, e

Comment: re why we'd bother: Money. Oodles of it gets put into space research ever since the first fakers. Kazillions. Certainly worth shooting space junk up, and dropping portions of similar looking space junk down. For the amount of money spent on space research I myself could orchestrate the same. Put on a show for the crowds. The original industry startup was several false productions which made loads of money, why do you think it ever changed? When ppl get onto a good lurch they tend to keep it going. You think the original producers took a career change and became scientists? Sounds unlikely.