# Beacons on everythig launched except none left on moon to prove a landing. Why???

Tags: nasa

6 times to the moon and nobody thought to bring a flashlight or a radio to send a beacon back to Earth to prove to one and all for all time we made it. But the Russians sent up Sputnik and the only thing it did was beep Just to prove they did it. Is nasa a fraud or just full of extremely incompetent people?

Comment: The signal for Apollo video broadcasts came from the moon. You can bet that other countries, especially Russia confirmed that there are actually astronauts on the moon.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether to downvote this for lack of research or upvote this to raise visibility into how easy it is to debunk some conspiracy theories, but decided to take the generous approach.

Comment: There may be at least one extremely incompetent people using the label Stumplifter.

Comment: You are wrong about Sputnik too. Sputnik transmitted telemetry,  temperature and pressure in the satellite were encoded in the duration of radio beeps.

Comment: Hi Stumplifter! You are getting downvoted because of the accusative tone of the question, which is very much a loaded question. If you edit the question to be "did NASA leave any beacons on the moon, if not, why not?" you will find that the question will be much better received by the Space Exploration community.

Comment: Given the tone of the question (and lack of homework done) I guess OP isn't even interested in a fact-driven answer, only one that confirms his conspiracy fantasy. Sometimes I wish we had a close reason for conspiracy fantasy questions.

Comment: @DarkDust https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28172/how-do-we-know-the-apollo-moon-landings-are-real/28173#28173

Answer (score 10):

Your assumption is incorrect. NASA did take all kinds of beacons to the Moon.

- Radio transmitters were used during the missions, for transmitting voice, telemetry and video.
- Each mission left an instrument package named [ALSEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Surface_Experiments_Package). These included radio transmitters, and they ran until 1977 when their RTGs ran out of power.
- Laser reflectors were placed, these can be pinged from Earth
- An optical beacon would be of limited value as it'd take a lot of power to make that visible on Earth

Comment: Apollo 11 left a simplified version called [EASEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Surface_Experiments_Package#Apollo_11_(EASEP)). But EASEP had a transmitter too.