# Why didn’t the astronauts on the moon ever get out of breath? Even while running, or falling down?

Tags: the-moon

My question is, even with the demand of learning how to walk and all the falls and and bumbling around of the astronauts, they never ran outta breath? Maybe in the newer missions they caught this and emplimented it into the dialog but in the early missions “which was even harder to get around”, they Never get out of breath, just running around laughing and cracking jokes with ease, like they were simply just standing, or sitting down talking in a microphone? Seems a little suspicious to me.

Comment: Ok for one, I’m not a consperacy theorist and I asked a question that I didnt, hear any consperacy theorists ask and I just thought of while watching some of the Apollo tapes. In a lot of the scenes the astronaughts are basically playing around on the moon laughing joking with ease even while falling down, never out of breath, or signs of interference of breathing like when Neil jumped out on the lunar surface the first time. Just seems strange to me.

Comment: and for two if your brain can’t comprehend knowing what astronauts could mean when it’s not spelled astronaughts, then maybe you shouldn’t be the one answering my question...

Comment: Then don’t make remarks that are not on topic, you clearly have a issue with moon hoax.

Comment: What do you mean by "a lot of the scenes"? What's your source here?

Comment: You're referring to "scenes" and "dialog", which is a framing suggesting a staged production. You claim to have "watched the complete missions", which seems unlikely, as the Apollo program included about 80 hours of lunar surface EVA time, most of which was documented by audio recording and photograph, rather than filmed; and you haven't specified any sources. Give us some help here.

Comment: Well trained and healthy man would not get out of breath from a very short exercise like standing up after falling down. They did a simple push-up with their arms to get up. This was possible due to the very low gravity of the moon despite the heavy and bulky suit and the backpack with the life support system.

Answer (score 7):

According to the detailed descriptions of the Apollo Project written about in [A Man On The Moon by Andrew Chaikin](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&safe=active&ei=EKZEXIb_GseEsAWi8qv4AQ&q=man%20on%20the%20moon%20andrew%20chaikin&oq=man%20on%20the%20moon%20andrew%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0j0i22i30l5.1174.4778..6081...2.0..0.87.669.10......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j33i22i29i30j33i160.2DHUygGcLDU), they did indeed "get out of breath"- despite being extremely physically fit.

Not only that, they also would bruise their fingers and have fingernails that looked smashed, like with a hammer, after working in their pressure suits for several hours.

A simple appraisal of a limited selection of popular audio clips is unsuitable for concluding that they didn't "get out of breath" during the EVAs conducted.

Comment: Ok, well it was the complete missions I watched, and I don’t remember exactly what scenes I’ll have to add more information on time stamps if you’d like, but clearly when there doing straining exercises it’s as if there unaffected, and talking fluently, even cracking jokes and talking normal.

Comment: @MattZabojnik The astronauts would go to some lengths to conceal any less-than-perfect health situation from mission control, because they hated the idea that the flight surgeon would order them to curtail any part of the mission. They would much rather bull through fatigue and get the job done than look weak over the radio.

Comment: So this was an issue already asked by someone? Because your answer seems like an excuse the astronaughts gave when someone figured  this out and thought it to be strange?

Comment: And look weak, meaning look weak to the Russians?

Comment: @RussellBorogove, indeed, as well as going to great length to conceal such situations from one another. Fear of flack from the flight surgeon coupled with the test pilot experience and background most of them had, there won't be much found. Previous comment redacted, upon further reflection.

Comment: @Preston they didn't want to look weak to the flight surgeon. A small hiccup or problem could cause flight objectives to be canceled. That was the last thing any astronaut wanted. While not as prominent, but still present, was an astronaut corps "bravado" related to the test pilot mindset many of them had.

Comment: @Preston Astronaut biographies are rife with examples of concealing injuries and illness.  Yeager hid broken ribs, the Apollo 8 crew concealed Frank Borman's intestinal bug. Getting grounded was among a pilot's or astronaut's worst fears: Deke Slayton and Alan Shepard were both grounded for years by health issues after going through astronaut training.

Comment: I’m sure a little out of breath wouldn’t of stoped the greatest achievement of mankind, other than accepting Jesus as our lord and savior :), tuffing things out and getting the job done no matter what is what our military strives for so why not astronaughts?

Comment: That's exactly what we're saying?

Comment: Pluss they were already on the moon, you can’t get grounded, on a point of no return, pluss the astronaughts could have done anything they wanted at this point, what would nasa do not help them get home afterwards in retaliation? Even nba stars are allowed to stay in a game if the coach asks how they feel and they say there ok, let me play coach

Comment: This has become conjecture and hypothetical speculation. If you want more information, read the biographies. Doing so will help with a greater understanding of the Manned Space Flight Program. "Toughing things out and getting the job done" is exactly what they did, and is what we are telling you they did. They didn't let something like physical exertion or illness cause any problems on the flights, by means of "toughing it out." Not showing weakness on the radio, including in their breathing, was part of that.

Comment: Ok so there thoughts were they didn’t want to get banned from future missions, but it still seems a little weird, thanks for your patients and comments I understand what your saying.

Comment: Just one last though, no matter how much you “try” to conceal something it still bleeds through, even players giving interviews are outta breath sometimes and have trouble talking, but ya i can see where your coming from, I hope this was the case, cause it’s kinda scary if it wasn’t lol. I guess nobody really knows only the astronauts, “even though Neal Armstrong won’t swear on the Bible he walked on the moon, could be he thought it to be an insult and refused to answer, like I said only he knows,

Comment: and hopefully all theories will be debunked by evedince instead of “this is how it could have happened” with evidence that sounds compelling but also undeniable and un flawed in anyway.

Comment: @MattZabojnik nice answer, welcome to space SE!

Comment: @Preston "I guess nobody really knows only the astronauts" - no. See https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/28172/how-do-we-know-the-apollo-moon-landings-are-real

Answer (score 5):

The weight of the life-support backback and the awkward bulkiness of the space-suits was to some degree compensated for by working in one-sixth gravity, but some of the lunar surface activity was indeed tiring.

While loading moon rocks and other gear back into the LM at the end of the Apollo 11 EVA, mission control was becoming concerned with Armstrong's [elevated heart rate](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11mr_fig12_3eng.gif), and asked him to check his suit systems as an excuse to get him to take a rest.

Listening to [this recording](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11a1105253-1113910.mp3) at around 37:30 to 39:30 in, you can hear Armstrong sounding slightly short-of-breath compared to Aldrin (who has the easier job at this moment); the request for EMU check is at 39:15.